# Как найти координаты наибольшего квадрата из единиц в матрице.Python

Tags: python, динамические-массивы

Сейчас решаю задачу. Решил применить формулу a[i][j] = min(a[i - 1][j - 1], a[i][j - 1], a[i - 1][j]) + 1. Теперь задаюсь вопросом, как мне найти координаты(x,y) этой квадратной матрицы?Код ниже:

```
coor = input().split()
N = coor[0]
W = coor[1] #Высота
H = coor[2] #Ширина
cl = []
score = 0
a = [[1 for y in range(int(W))] for x in range(int(H)+1)]
for x in range(int(N)):
    tree_coor = input().split()
    x = int(tree_coor[0])
    y = int(tree_coor[1])
    a[y][x] = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if i*j != 0:
            if a[i][j] == 1:
                a[i][j] = min(a[i - 1][j - 1], a[i][j - 1], a[i - 1][j]) + 1
            if (a[i][j] > score):
                score=a[i][j]
print(score)
```

Comment: Так у вас максимум в матрице это размер наибольшего. Та клетка где максимум это угол квадрата. Так как вы идете слева и вниз, то всегда правый нижний

Comment: Я это уже понял, но как мне найти координаты квадрата?То есть x и y начала квадрата со стороны левого нижнего угла

Comment: Пусть максимум 9 в клетке (6, 8)- правый нижний угол. Тогда размер квадратра 3х3 и левый верхний (6-3, 8-3)=(3,5)

Comment: Извиняюсь что сам затупил, забыл одну вещь в условие, поэтому задал вопрос